# Trouble passing data from TableViewCell labels to a ViewController

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

I am trying to pass data from the selected cell of an "Events" table view, to a "Details" View Controller. I have looked at various questions similar to mine, but I can't seem to properly apply it to my code. I also used labels, instead of a Subtitle style. There is also an image that needs to be passed.

my view controller looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var names = ["BTown Diner", "Dunnkirk", "Chocolate Mousse", "Lil Wayne", "Annie", "Campus Squad Social"]
    var details = ["Free drink with meal after 12 AM", "LADIES drink free", "10% off all ice cream!", "Lil 500 concert", "an IU Theater Production", "Bring your Squad to the Campus Squad Social"]
    var images = [UIImage(named: "btown"), UIImage(named: "dunn"), UIImage(named: "choco"), UIImage(named: "lilwayne"), UIImage(named: "default"), UIImage(named: "default")]




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row]
        cell.detail.text = details[indexPath.row]
        cell.photo.image = images[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    var valueToPass:String!

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

        // Get Cell Label
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;

        valueToPass = currentCell.textLabel.text
        performSegueWithIdentifier("detailsSegue", sender: self)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "detailsSegue") {

            // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
            var viewController = segue.destinationViewController as detailsViewController
            // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
            viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
        }

    }

}
```

and here is my customCell.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var photo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var detail: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I am very new to Swift, and it has proven to be very challenging for me. I'm really not a coder, however a project demands that I complete some of the coding for an application that I am the UI/UIX designer of. Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to register your "CustomCell" with the name "cell"

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, that seemed like it worked for a second, then I was returned with my favorite signal SIGABRT error. Would you why this is? I know in the passed when this has happened its usually a naming issue? This is hard, ha.

Comment: Please track the error log in your console to see where the SIGABRT happened.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight variation on your code starting with the main view controller...

```
import UIKit

class EventTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var names = ["BTown Diner", "Dunnkirk", "Chocolate Mousse", "Lil Wayne", "Annie", "Campus Squad Social"]
    var details = ["Free drink with meal after 12 AM", "LADIES drink free", "10% off all ice cream!", "Lil 500 concert", "an IU Theater Production", "Bring your Squad to the Campus Squad Social"]
    var images = [UIImage(named: "btown"), UIImage(named: "dunn"), UIImage(named: "choco"), UIImage(named: "lilwayne"), UIImage(named: "default"), UIImage(named: "default")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row]
        cell.detail.text = details[indexPath.row]
        cell.photo.image = images[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "detailsSegue" {
            guard let eventVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailsViewController,
                  let eventIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else {
                      return
                  }
            eventVC.eventName = names[eventIndex]
            eventVC.eventDetail = details[eventIndex]
            eventVC.eventPhoto = images[eventIndex]
        } 
    } 
}
```

and then a sample detailsViewController...

```
import UIKit

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    var eventName: String = ""
    var eventDetail: String = ""
    var eventPhoto: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(eventName)
        print(eventDetail)
    }
}
```

You were off to a good start.  Hope this helps get you the rest of the way.

Comment: First off, thank you so much. Seeing your answer in my inbox was like a gift from the Heavens I am not exaggerating this is haunting my dreams. I ran the code you provided, however I am returning errors in a few lines.

Comment: class `EventTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { ` "redundant conformance of 'EventTableViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'",  two times, also `let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell` "use of undeclared type 'CustomCell'

Comment: First, delete UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate from the first line. They must already be set in the Storyboard. To fix the second problem, go to Storyboard and select your table cell.  Find the Identity Inspector and make sure Custom Class > Class is set to CustomCell.  Just to be safe, next find the Attributes Inspector and set the Identifier to "cell" (without the parentheses.)